# Can't instantiate abstract class with abstract methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, python-2.x, abstract-methods

I'm working on a kind of lib, and I'm getting an error.

- [Here](https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-fantasy-sport/blob/master/fantasy_sport/roster.py) is my code. Of course *@abc.abstractmethod have to be uncommented*
- [Here](https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-fantasy-sport/blob/master/tests.py#L206-247) are my tests

*Sorry couldn't just copy and paste it*

I went on the basis that the code below works.

#### test.py:

```
import abc
import six

@six.add_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)
class Base(object):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def whatever(self,):
        raise NotImplementedError

class SubClass(Base):

    def __init__(self,):
    
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.whatever()

    def whatever(self,):
        print("whatever")
```

In the python shell:

```
>>> from test import *
>>> s = SubClass()
whatever
```

For my *roster* module, why am I getting this error:

```
Can't instantiate abstract class Player with abstract methods _Base__json_builder, _Base__xml_builder
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Your issue comes because you have defined the abstract methods in your base abstract class with `__` (double underscore) prepended. This causes python to do [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) at the time of definition of the classes.

The names of the function change from `__json_builder` to `_Base__json_builder` or `__xml_builder` to `_Base__xml_builder` . And this is the name you have to implement/overwrite in your subclass.

To show this behavior in your example -

```
>>> import abc
>>> import six
>>> @six.add_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)
... class Base(object):
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def __whatever(self):
...             raise NotImplementedError
...
>>> class SubClass(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(Base, self).__init__()
...             self.__whatever()
...     def __whatever(self):
...             print("whatever")
...
>>> a = SubClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class SubClass with abstract methods _Base__whatever
```

When I change the implementation to the following, it works

```
>>> class SubClass(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(Base, self).__init__()
...             self._Base__whatever()
...     def _Base__whatever(self):
...             print("whatever")
...
>>> a = SubClass()
whatever
```

But this is very tedious , you may want to think about if you really want to define your functions with `__` (double underscore) . You can read more about name mangling [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) .

Comment: Thanks @AnandSKumar, it's weird because i tried it lol. Have good one buddy

Comment: Am I the only one, who stumbled upon the Error Message? Maybe it's just me, but I'd expect something along these lines: _Can't instantiate subclass of abstract class Base __without__ methods some-method_. This confused me at first.

Comment: @quapka I think the error message seems fine. The error message indicates that the SubClass class has an 'abstract method' <some method> , and its not a concrete method, hence we cannot instantiate an object of it.

Comment: @quapka I agree. The error message `Can't instantiate abstract class Foo with abstract methods abstract_method` is clearly wrong. The problem is not that an abstract class is being instantiated with a forbidden method, but that a subclass of  an abstract class is being instantiated _without_ a required method. It should say something like `Can't instantiate subclass Foo of abstract class Bar without method abstract_method_that_must_be_overridden`.

Comment: @Arthur You are an abstract class when you have abstract methods, so the error message is not wrong. If the abstract methods were overriden, you would not have abstract methods, and consequently you would not be an abstract class.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the clarification. The error message is indeed really confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Animal with abstract methods sound

When I tried to instantiate **`Animal` abstract class** as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self):
        print("Wow!!")

obj = Animal() # Here
obj.sound()
```

And also, I got the same error below:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Cat with abstract methods sound

When I didn't override **`sound()` abstract method** in **`Cat` class**, then I instantiated **`Cat` class** as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self):
        print("Wow!!")

class Cat(Animal):
    pass # I didn't override "sound()" abstract method

obj = Cat() # Here
obj.sound()
```

So, I overrided **`sound()` abstract method** in **`Cat` class**, then I instantiated **`Cat` class** as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self):
        print("Wow!!")

# I overrided "sound()" abstract method
class Cat(Animal):
    def sound(self):
        print("Meow!!")

obj = Cat() # Here
obj.sound()
```

Then, I could solve the error:

```
Meow!!
```

Answer (score 2):

The error text is a bit inaccurate.
To be precise, you did not override the method of the parent class,
because **private** methods and attributes cannot be inherited,
which means they cannot be overridden.

But you can override **protected** methods (protected method should start with single underscore '_').

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to make it behave like it did in Python 2 is to use

```
exec('print("your code")', globals())
```

This will allow your code to access imports, classes and functions defined in the code will work correctly, etc.

This should only be done w/ code you trust.